# WiFi not as fast as expected with MT7921 wireless network adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I am getting the following speed:

```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 85.89 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 101.58 Mbit/s
```

On the same machine (dual-boot) on Windows 11 I am getting ~780Mbit/s.

I want to achieve similar speed on my Ubuntu installation, the MTU size is configured as 1500. I have been searching online for some answers but was not able to find something to resolve my issue.

I'm on a ThinkBook e15 with a MT7921 wireless network adapter.

**Edit1**: output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

enx806d975284d1  no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"KRZHKFHZ5330"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: D0:20:F8:B9:50:C5   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**Edit2**:
As @vidarlo correctly pointed out the reason for getting lower speed is because my Wi-Fi was connected to 2.4GHz band. I was able to resolve this by changing my Wi-Fi configuration:
`sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<my-wifi-ssid>` and adding `band=a` (5Ghz only) to the `[wifi]` column.

Then saved and closed, reconnected:

```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 426.10 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 380.42 Mbit/s
```

```
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"KRZHKFHZ5330"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: D0:20:F8:B9:50:C5   
          Bit Rate=720.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: What's the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and replace it with an Intel 3165

Comment: Hi @vidarlo I've updated the post :)

Comment: @Jeremy31 I found that there is no official Linux driver on the MediaTek website, perhaps that explains my problems, not actually sure how it is working in the first place then...
But I suppose that's a good alternative, although I would prefer not to purchase something new of course.

Comment: @jwielink in general that's not a big concern; support is included in the kernel, it's never downloaded in general ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"KRZHKFHZ5330"
> Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: D0:20:F8:B9:50:C5

You're connected to a 2.4GHz AP with the adapter. On 2.4GHz, 100Mb/s is a good max speed; you're unlikely to go much higher.

To get higher speed, you have to connect on the 5GHz band, on a 802.11ax access point.

Comment: I'm on the road now and found that my speed is higher now on my hotspot
```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 198.87 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 0.42 Mbit/s
```
I will try this when I'm home ^